# Using a sub-string of the column name in creating index in CockroachDB

Tags: database, substring, cockroachdb, table-index

Moving from Oracle to CockroachDB, I'm using a index creating command as below:

`CREATE INDEX ON "sales" (substring("a",0,19), substring("b",20,2), "c");`

The error I get is:

```
invalid syntax: statement ignored: unimplemented at or near ")"
CREATE INDEX ON "sales" (substring("a",0,19), substring("b",20,2), "c");
```

I have also used: `substr`

but the error is the same.

--

Edit1:
The error for the modified command

`CREATE INDEX ON "sales" (substring("a",0,19));`

will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a *computed index* - an index with keys that are more complex than column references. CockroachDB doesn't support computed indexes yet.

There's an open issue for adding support for computed indexes:

https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/9682

Answer (score 0):

[Cockroach-DB Create INDEX Sypnosis.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Iuq.png)

According to the automata that validates the string to create an index in a table, there is no possibility to make use of the substring function.